# How to test or debug a portion of code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am quite new to Visual Studio and I am originally a LabVIEW programmer. I am very thankful for the great advantages a language like C# has to offer. But there is one thing that I currently miss and I think it should be possible with Visual Studio, but I simply do not know how:

In LabVIEW if I want to test a function (they call it VI) then I can simply run that VI by setting the input parameters and pressing "play". That way it is very easy to test low level functions without the need to run the complete application.

I know that something like this can be done with Unit Testing, but at first glance it seems quite complicated and like a comparably high amount of effort to always set up a test.

What is the correct way to test those low level methods in development stage with Visual Studio?

My current solution (yeah I know this is a very bad solution) is to create another project in the solution and somehow to link or copy the code I want to test and to start the debugger there.

I would be very greatful for a give-that-rookie-a-hint :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into something called "unit testing".

Comment: Unit testing is the usual way - not too hard to set up really.

Comment: Right click a class or method and choose to "Create Unit Test(s)". Accept the default options. Now you will have a separate project for your tests and some dummy tests created. You can debug the tests (put a breakpoint in them first) and use the tests to step through your code method by method

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing that. That was exactly what I was looking for. I did not know that using UnitTests was that easy and yet that versatile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit testing is a very convenient and practical way to test and debug code in it. The following is a simple example using Microsoft's official MSTest:

I have two functions as follows:

```
   public static double Add(double d1, double d2)

    {
        return d1 + d2;

    }



    public static bool IamTrue()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

At this point, if I right-click on a function and click Create Unit Test, the Create Unit Test menu will appear and click OK to generate the corresponding unit test case.

[image]

[image]

Here is a use case to generate unit tests for two functions:

```
[TestClass()]
public class CalculateTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void AddTest()
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void IamTrueTest()
    {
        
         Assert.Fail();
        
    }
}
```

But we need to change the original unit test case according to the characteristics of the function, as shown below after the change:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void AddTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(Calculate.Add(1, 2), 3);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void IamTrueTest()
    {
        if (Calculate.IamTrue() == false)
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
```

Right-click and click Run Tests to test whether the method works as expected

[image]

The following indicates a successful run:

[image]

You can also debug the function in the unit test. After setting a breakpoint where you want to debug, right-click in the unit test and click Debug Tests to debug the function.

[image]

[image]

Note: Please ensure that your program can run normally before unit testing